# How do I write to Json file in C#?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity. I was trying to make an Options menu, but my apply button does not work. I wanted to make it so the options gets written to a Json file.

I have tried that, but I just get this error:

```
Assets/Scripts/SettingsManager.cs(48,39): error CS0117: 'JsonUtility' does not contain a definition for 'toJson'
```

Here is the C# file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class SettingsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Toggle fullscreenToggle;
    public Dropdown resolutionDropdown;


    public Resolution[] resolutions;
    public GameSettings gameSettings;
    public Button applyButton;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        gameSettings = new GameSettings();

        fullscreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { OnFullscreenToggle(); });
        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { OnResolutionChange(); });
        applyButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { OnApplyButtonClick(); });

        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        foreach (Resolution resolution in resolutions)
        {
            resolutionDropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(resolution.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public void OnFullscreenToggle()
    {
        gameSettings.fullScreen = Screen.fullScreen = fullscreenToggle.isOn;
    }

    public void OnResolutionChange()
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(resolutions[resolutionDropdown.value].width, resolutions[resolutionDropdown.value].height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }

    public void OnApplyButtonClick()
    {
        SaveSettings();
    }
    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        string jsonData = JsonUtility.toJson(gameSettings, true);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesettings.json",jsonData);
    }

    public void LoadSettings()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `ToJson` instead of `toJson`? [because case matters](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo. Write ToJson with uppercase T

```
JsonUtility.ToJson
```

Comment: We don't answer typo based questions here on SO. This answer should rather be a comment and the question closed as off-topic due to produced by a typo and therefore not really helpful for the future.